# Magento2.1.7 generating wrong thumbnail image cache

Tags: catalog, magento-2.1.7

I have imported products in bulk via CSV in magento2, and all products imported successfully.

But for some products only thumbnail image generating wrong (it is showing other product's image where product's image name is same, but it should be created with different image name) `/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/thumbnail/75x75/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/1/1/1145.jpg`, all others images cache are same to product original image.

I tried to clean image cache but every time magento generating 75X75 cache image wrong for some products.

How to resolve it?